# Tabla HTML a Excel (usando javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, excel, mvc

Estoy teniendo el siguiente problema al descargar un archivo xls desde javascript.
Mi código es el siguiente:
[image: Código javascript]

Y el resultado al abrir el excel es este:

[image: Resultado Excel]

El a.href contiene esto:

```
    data:application/vnd.ms-excel, 
<html>
    <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <style>
          td {
              border: 0.5pt solid #c0c0c0
          } 
          .tRight {
              text-align:right
          } 
          .tLeft { 
              text-align:left
          } 
       </style>
    </head>
    <body>
       <table>
          <thead>
             <tr>
                <td>Concepto</td>
                <td>Fecha</td>
                <td>F.%20Imputacion</td>
                <td>Descripcion</td>
                <td>Moneda</td>
                <td>Importe</td>
             </tr>
          </thead>
       <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td>5040%20-%20Gastos</td>
             <td>23-11-2018</td>
             <td>2-11-2018</td>
             <td>Sube%20-%20Ingreso</td>
             <td>Peso</td>
             <td>65.00</td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

En formato html. Es una tabla html creada en el frontend.

Gracias por la ayuda!!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden, También si puedes quitar la captura de código y cambiarlo por código copiable, como el que tienes de la tabla será mejor recibida

Comment: Si está en formato HTML, no es formato XLS, así que es normal que Excel no sepa qué hacer con ella

Answer (score 2, accepted):

la referencia no esta bien formada seria mejor que el contenido lo declares como un blob y lo agregues como el url de recurso en la referencia,
algo como lo siguiente:

```js
function exportTableToExcel(tableID, filename = ''){
    var downloadLink;
    var dataType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
    var tableSelect = document.getElementById(tableID);
    var tableHTML = tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
    
    // nombre de archivo
    filename = filename?filename+'.xls':'excel_data.xls';
    
    // referencia agregada
    downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    
    if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
        var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', tableHTML], {
            type: dataType
        });
        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, filename);
    }else{
        // link de archivo
        downloadLink.href = 'data:' + dataType + ', ' + tableHTML;
    
        //el nombre archivo a link
        downloadLink.download = filename;
        
        //ejecutando la descarga
        downloadLink.click();
    }
}
```

```html
  <table id='tblGastos'>
          <thead>
             <tr>
                <td>Concepto</td>
                <td>Fecha</td>
                <td>F.Imputacion</td>
                <td>Descripcion</td>
                <td>Moneda</td>
                <td>Importe</td>
             </tr>
          </thead>
       <tbody>
          <tr>
             <td>Gastos</td>
             <td>23-11-2018</td>
             <td>2-11-2018</td>
             <td>SubeIngreso</td>
             <td>Peso</td>
             <td>65.00</td>
         </tr>
       </tbody>
     </table>
                
                <button onclick="exportTableToExcel('tblGastos', 'Gastos')">Exportar a Excel</button>
```

Con esta referencia el cliente descarga tu tabla como excel.